# Importing matlab data into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polyline-creation, matlab

I'm creating regression lines using matlab from points having UTM geographic coordinates.

I would like to import those regression lines into a map of the same area in ArcMap.

What kind of data do I need to extract from Matlab to be read and imported as polylines in ArcMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@PolyGeo points out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22418/115), convert to shapefile.  Looks like you can do this in the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/description2.html).

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be a related question and answer over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550335/writing-lon-lat-coordinates-to-a-shapefile-in-matlab-with-projection) that incorporates what looks like a solution to this question.  It suggests that shapefile may be the easiest format to use.